# Displaying nonspatial data via spatial data in Leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet, api, ajax

I have two pieces of data; one is nonSpatial Jobs data and one is a spatial grid (polygon that was turned into geoJson). They are being served through separate API's/ajax calls. A primary-foreign key was created to link the two datasets(Cell ID or CID that is created from the southwest coordinate of each grid cell. Ex n89, w113 = CID:n89w113). My goal is for the user to be able to create and display the Jobs data based on the grid cell. Thus fa, I have not been able to achieve this. Assuming that a job already exist with a certain CID (but this job has no spatial value-lat/lng) and there is a corresponding grid cell that has that same CID and is spatial located on a map, how can I use Leaflet (or just javascript) to display the information for the Job corresponding to that grid cell (using a mouseover/click event and popup method like .bindPopup)? Here's my current logic, but I think there is something amiss...

```
 var globalArrayJobsCID = [];
 $.ajax for Jobs data{
   ...
   data.forEach(function (value) {
     var cid = value.cid;
     globalArrayJobsCID.push(cid);
   ...
   };
   $.getJSON("url', function(data) {
     grid = L.geoJson(data, {...};
     onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
     var id = feature.properties.cid;
     globalJobsArrayCID.forEach (item) {
        if(item == id) {
          layer.bindPopup(<Jobs data>);
   });
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `globalArrayJobsCID`, you just push the `cid`, not the associated `value`. And I guess you actually want to show that `value` (i.e. an item from your `data`), not the `cid` itself (or not only that).

Furthermore, in your 2nd step, when you loop through your `globalArrayJobsCID` to find matches with each polygon / grid cell, you override the layer popup. This may not be a problem if you are sure that you have at most 1 job per polygon. Otherwise, you will display only the last one.

Therefore your code should rather look like:

```js
var globalArrayJobsCID = [];
var grid;

$.ajax("url-for-ajax").done(function (data) {
  // if your data is a simple array, you could even just use it directly
  // instead of globalArrayJobsCID, or globalArrayJobsCID = data
  data.forEach(function (value) {
    globalArrayJobsCID.push(value);
  });

  $.getJSON("url", function (data) {
    grid = L.geoJson(data {
      onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
        var id = feature.properties.cid;
        var popupContent = "";

        globalArrayJobsCID.forEach(function (item) {
          if (item.cid === id) {
            // Assuming you want to display item.jobData
            popupContent += "Job: " + item.jobData + "<br />";
          }
        });

        if (popupContent) {
          layer.bindPopup(popupContent);
        }
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Hey-That worked! I still need to tweek it to get it to display the rest of the jobs data (creator name, date created, lat/lng, etc...) but I have it properly displaying the cid for the job when you mouseover the grid cell with the same cid (I added a `layer.on ('mouseover/mouseout', function (e) ...` on the cells).